# Am I using get_posts wrong?

Tags: theme-development, get-posts

I have

```
<?php 
$folioPosts = get_posts(array('category_name' => 'portfolio', 'numberposts' => 3));
if ($folioPosts->have_posts()) :
foreach ($folioPosts as $folioPost) : 
setup_postdata($folioPost);
?>

<article class="col3">
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></a></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></p>
</article>

<?php
endforeach;
else :
?>
<p>No folio posts to display ...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am getting

> Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object ...

I think its because my args to get_posts are wrong. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_posts()` returns an array, not a `WP_Query` object.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) If you want to use `have_posts()` and related functions, use a "raw" `WP_Query` object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that to work, instead of this:

```
if ($folioPosts->have_posts()) :
```

try this:

```
if( !empty( $folioPosts ) ) :
```

Also, after the foreach line and before setup_postdata, add something like this:

```
global $post; $post = $folioPost;
```

Comment: Could you explain why I need `$post = $folioPost` and what does `setup_postdata()` do? I can't find this info in the docs

Comment: `setup_postdata()` overwrites all the post-related globals used by the template tags except for $post. Since some template tags do make use of the global `$post`, that needs to be changed to reflect the current item in your custom loop.