# WP_Query vs get_posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, query, get-posts

I have read a [**number**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) [of](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9630/am-i-using-get-posts-wrong?lq=1) [**questions**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) on SE regarding these but I still can't figure the exact difference wrt usage. Would it be true to say that I would probably use WP_Query for the majority of secondary loops and only use get_posts if I need the results returned in an array, or to put it another way is the main difference between the two the array vs object return, or is there some other major factor I should be aware of?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The difference between get_posts & WP_Query

You can view `get_posts()` as a slimmed down `WP_Query`. In fact looking at the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1433):

```
//... prepares query array $r
$get_posts = new WP_Query;
return $get_posts->query($r);
```

`get_posts()` use `WP_Query`, but only returns an array of posts - nothing more. Furthermore it sets:

```
$r['no_found_rows'] = true;
```

Normally (by default with `WP_Query` object) - WordPress queries how many posts there are in total - even if you are only after the first 10. It does this so it can perform pagination. So `get_posts()` is actually (slightly) quicker (it also ignores sticky posts).

#### Which to use...

If you only need an array of posts, and don't *need* the query object -use `get_posts()`. Otherwise, if you do need the access to the query object methods, or pagination, or sticky posts at the top,  you should use `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to note is that `get_posts()` has a bunch of default arguments that `new WP_Query()` doesn't have, which include `post_type` and `post_status`. The function's defaults are configured to facilitate getting published posts. If you want something different, you'll need to pass in thos parameters explicitly, whereas with `WP_Query()` you wouldn't have to do that.

For example, if you want to get all posts, regardless of their post status, you would need to call: `get_posts( array( "post_type" => 'any' ) );` (leaving "post_type" blank - or anything that `empty()` would evaluate to `true` will cause `get_posts()` to apply its default value of "publish").

Comment: `WP_Query` has those same post type and status defaults.

Comment: @Milo Are you sure? Look at class-wp-query.php lines 1742 - 1746. I believe the default for `post_type` is "", or "any" for tax queries. The docs seem to support this as well.

Comment: Post type defaults to `any` in certain circumstances, like a search or some tax queries. Run a new `WP_Query` and pass only `posts_per_page`, it will default to post.