# Using get_posts vs. WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, cache

I'm running [the following PHP Code Sniffs](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) on some WordPress code, and the following warning pops up

```
 352 | WARNING | get_posts is discouraged in favor of creating a new
     |         | WP_Query() so that Advanced Post Cache will cache
     |         | the query, unless you explicitly supply
     |         | suppress_filters => false.
```

While I'm an experienced programmer, I'm not super familiar with WordPress's history.  This warning seems important, but is awkwardly worded. I'm confused on a few points, and [other answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/wp-query-vs-get-posts) I've [found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) on the [subject](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) don't seem to address my points.

1. What is the "Advanced Post Cache".  I know WordPress (like a lot of PHP applications) has caching going on at a few different levels.
2. Is this warning telling me that `get_posts` will never use the cache, but `WP_Query` will?
3. Is this warning telling me that using `suppress_filters` with `WP_Query` will bypass the Advanced Post Cache?  Or that using `suppress_filters` with `get_posts` will invoke the cache?  Or something else?
4. What else does `suppress_filters` do?

If someone more familiar with the matter could clue in a WordPress newb I'd appreciate it.  I'm not looking for a "always use X, or never use Y" sort of answer -- I'm trying to understand the tradeoffs of each approach.

Comment: I would recommend always using `WP_Query`, it's what `get_posts` uses internally. Also as an aside, never use `query_posts` under any circumstances, and always remember to cleanup with `wp_reset_postdata`

Comment: if I've answered your question don't forget you can mark it as correct, or comment on it if it didn't

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit: WP Core has changed since the question and answer were written. While I still believe it's better to use `WP_Query` for other reasons, the `suppress_filters` rule should be gone from WPCS/VIPCS now**

**See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/1416#issuecomment-1311724183 for why**

As for which you should use, use `WP_Query` directly. `get_posts` uses it internally, and running the post loop fires lifecycle hooks that don't happen when you use `get_posts` with a `foreach` loop. You're also forcing WP to return an array of full posts, increasing memory footprint and eliminating opportunities to lazyload.

---

*Parts of Original Answer:*

## WP_Cache

The original concern behind the sniff was that get_posts suppressed the use of WP Cache, which is no longer the case. Hence why the sniff mentions advanced cache.

Normally when WP fetches a post, it stores it in `WP_Cache` along with all its terms and post meta. This is why repeatedly calling `get_post_meta` doesn't repeatedly query the database.

This is why a common mistake in new WP developers is to try and create variable caches to avoid database queries, WordPress already does this. Unfortunately these variable based caches do not live beyond that page request and are empty on the next request as a result.

### Persistent WP_Cache `object-cache.php` and `advanced-cache.php`

However, there are plugins and drop in files that provide `advanced-cache.php` or `object-cache.php`, which can make `WP_Cache`be made persistent. This is usually done by storing the data in software such as Redis/Memcached or another 3rd party data store that runs in the background in memory.

For example, `batcache` will make `WP_Cache` use `memcached` to store things, letting data persist between page loads, improving performance significantly. There are similar plugins for Redis/memcache/etc, and **they can give HUGE performance gains**.

Enabling a persistent object cache with dedicated software can give massive performance benefits that rival the biggest hardware even when used on the tiniest of servers, often times eliminating most if not all database queries.

Note that this is different from caching things in files/folders.